# How to avoid negative values from css calc function?

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I am using [css calc function from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/)

```css
calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - [minimum viewport width])));
```

I use the calc function like this

```css
margin-top: calc(270px + (0 - 270) * (100vw - 320px) / (900 - 320));
```

This works and my `margin-right` is 270px at 320px viewport width and 0px at 900px viewport width.
But when I resize my window bigger than `900px`, the `margin-right` is negative.

I can use media queries, but is there another CSS solution? Can I combine these calc function with `min()` `max()` or `clamp()` to avoid negative values?

**Edit**

i found a possible solution. It works with `max()` in this way

```css
margin-right: max(0vw, calc(270px + (0 - 270) * ((100vw - 320px) / (900 - 320))))
```

Comment: why dont you adjust it with media query to adjust your calcul ?

Comment: @MaxiGui i want to use as few media queries as possible in my project and it tears me apart to combine the css functions perfectly, if possible, so that you can do without for example media queries in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for all who are interested. I ended up with this css rules.

if your minimum value is negative you need the css `min()` function like this

```css
margin-right: min(0vw, calc(-270px + (0 - -270) * ((100vw - 320px) / (900 - 320))))
```

if your minimum value is positive you need the css `max()` function like this

```css
margin-right: max(0vw, calc(270px + (0 - 270) * ((100vw - 320px) / (900 - 320))))
```

Comment: You welcome for correction and giving you answer...